# Updating a control from another control child

Tags: c#, xaml

I have some problems trying to update components of surface elements. I dont know if my approach to the problem is wrong, since I'm new to the topic.

My point is represented by the following diagram

[image]

According to the option that is selected in the menu, load different user controls as only child of StackPanel but i'm habing problems for update the Listview from loaded user controls, example: when I save a new item I need to recharge the list of items in the ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM would be a good pattern here. If you have a problem passing data between controls - why not introduce them on top of unified data layer? Consider this:

Three radio buttons in your Menu, each one's `IsChecked` property bound to `Visibility` property of your respective `UserControl`.

`StackPanel` holding all three `UserControls`

`ListView` bound to ViewModel's `List<Item>`

Each of your `UserControls` bound to `ListView.SelectedItem`: one of them using `TextBlock` for read-only, one using `TextBox` for editing. Third one would create new item in your `List<Item>`. You would have to create `ItemTemplate` for each or create one `UserControl` (since they look very much alike) and use `DataTemplateSelector`.

If you're not familiar with MVVM [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html) is a good start. You can also use one of the existing frameworks like [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

Comment: For a simple project, it is best to use the pattern directly or use a framework? I do not want to install unnecessary things and make my project complex

Comment: I'd say start on your own, get to know key things (DataContext, binding, commanding etc) but at some stage you'll find that pre-made framework will save you lots of time.

Comment: you're right. I have installed MVVM Light But certainly the documentation is not good; A tutorial like this one http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/creating/ leaves much to be desired

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event on your child

```
public delegate void HandleNAMEOFYOURHANDLEEVENT();
```

on your child class

```
public event HandleNAMEOFYOURHANDLEEVENT yourInstance;
```

to use it on your child class

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(yourInstance, null))
                        {
                            yourInstance();
                        }
```

and you declare it on your parent like other event.